# Assign a variable inside of a scriptblock while running a job

Tags: powershell, powershell-jobs

Related to [Terminate part of powershell script and continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49675541/terminate-part-of-powershell-script-and-continue).
Partially related to [Powershell Job Always Shows Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27876755/powershell-job-always-shows-complete).

My script runs locally and access the registry hive of a remote PC. I need the value of registry keys to be written into a `$RegHive` variable. And I want to monitor it as a job in case some PC freezes, I can terminate the command and move on to another PC.

My original code would be:

```
$global:RegHive = $null
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    $RegHive = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("SomeKeyName", "SomePCName")
}
```

But no matter what I do, the variable `$RegHive` is empty.

If I do `$RegHive = (Get-Job | Receive-Job)` some value gets assigned to `$RegHive` that on one side looks exactly as if I would run it normally without a job/scriptblock, ie:

```
$RegHive = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("SomeKeyName", "SomePCName")
```

and even has the same `$RegHive.SubKeyCount`

But the "normal" one has `$RegHive.GetSubKeyName()` method and the one from job doesn't.

How do I escape assigning a variable with `Receive-Job` and do the assignment directly inside the scriptblock, which is run as a job?

In simple words:

```
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {$a = 1 + 2}
```

How to get `$a` be equal to 3 without `$a = (Get-job | Receive-job)`?

Comment: Jobs executed in separate process. Live objects can not be passed thru process boundary.

Comment: @PetSerAl, so is it impossible then? No workaround? Like maybe passing pointers as parameters/global variables/calling functions that write into global variables(I tried the last 2, but couldn't make it work)?

Comment: Yes. Besides, I fail to see why you'd even want to pass back the hive object instead of finishing the work inside the job.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers The point is: i need the value of the key itself (call it `$RegHive`) to be used later. Otherwise I would have to add the entire script inside this job and deal with key value there. Idk if that makes sense...

Comment: The real question is, on such a quick operation as calling a registry value, why do you need to assign it a job at all? - nvm you stated you have issues with getsubkeyname()

Comment: Why not just use the regular way, and use `select-object` to just remove getsubkeynames something like `select-object -ExcludeProperty GetSubKeyNames`

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful for you. The job is sort of like a variable
What you can do is name the job and then call it by name with `-Keep` to maintain it's value stored - aka it will store all final output inside itself until you call it. (it can be kept but the default is to remove it once called)

```
$global:RegHive = $null
Start-Job -Name "RegHive" -ScriptBlock {
    [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("SomeKeyName", "SomePCName")
}
Receive-Job -Name "RegHive" -Keep
```

obviously calling the `Receive-Job` immediately after defeats the purpose of jobs, they add a lot of overhead, and are only efficient when needing to do multiple things at once. - if you call for 100s or thousands at once, you could do `get-job | wait-job` then when finished start using their outputs ---- `wait-job` also accepts job names or can wait on your entire list of jobs.

another option to set the variable is

```
$RegHive = "Receive-Job -Name "RegHive"
```

and finally, you can do this to use the value

```
get-<insert command> -value "$(Receive-Job -Name 'RegHive' -Keep)" -argument2 "YADA YADA"
```

remember keep will not delete the value and can be "Received" again later.